# Emulate ARM Cortex-M4 with qemu

Tags: arm, qemu, cortex-m

I have a program consisting of multiple C source files and I would like to execute it in qemu with a Cortex-M4/M7 CPU. I am using the following command to build the objects:

```
"arm-none-eabi-gcc" -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -fomit-frame-pointer -Wimplicit-fallthrough -O3 -Wall -Wshadow -Wcast-qual -Wno-long-long -Wno-unknown-pragmas
```

The linker creates a library:

```
arm-none-eabi-ar cru lib *.o
```

And the main is then linked to an executable:

```
"arm-none-eabi-gcc" -mthumb -specs=rdimon.specs main.o lib.a  -lstdc++ -lm -L./lib/arm_none-eabi_gcc/  -o run_main
```

Now running this binary gives me:

```
qemu-arm -cpu cortex-m4 run_main
qemu: uncaught target signal 4 (Illegal instruction) - core dumped
Illegal instruction
```

It all works well when using Cortex-A9 as CPU, but the M-Models are troubling me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does your linker script look like?  what does your vector table look like?  what system are you wanting to run (cortex-m4 is a system it is just the core, most of the system is not arm).

Comment: start with something simple (assembly language no C nor C++, then asm plus C then well down the road C++ and libraries)

Comment: did you look at the other qemu cortex-m answers on SO?

Comment: qemu-arm is the "execute an ELF file that's a Linux binary" program. Are you sure you wanted that and not qemu-system-arm, which is the "execute something to run on emulated bare-metal hardware" ? Whichever you wanted, the required way to compile it will differ...

Answer (score 1):

ARM Cortex-M MCUs always require custom linker script and startup code. Flash and RAM addresses are not standardized across vendors, and the interrupt vector table is device specific.

The linker command line should also specify the core via "-mcpu=cortex-m4" in order to link to the correct libraries (multilib).